# magento 2 displays small picture in catalog

Tags: magento2, product-view, view

My magento 2 was fine, I upload big image and the display was fine, now, new products show up small (the one in the right), see my screenshot : 
[image]

I didnt edit my *view.xml* so I dont know how this suddenly occured!!!
both image in the catalog page are the same size in fact, but obviously whn I uploaded the image, magento makes the pic small and a big frame around.

here is a part of my view.xml:

```
    <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image"> <!--page categories product list height -->
        <!--<width>925</width>
        <height>1388</height>-->
        <width>1800</width>
        <height>2700</height>
    </image>
    <image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>325</height>
    </image>
    <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>800</height>
    </image>
    <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
        <width>100</width>
        <height>117</height>
    </image>
    <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
        <width>279</width>
        <height>325</height>
    </image>
    <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
        <width>100</width>
        <height>117</height>
    </image>
    <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
        <width>75</width>
        <height>87</height>
    </image>
    <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
        <width>100</width>
        <height>117</height>
    </image>
    <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
        <width>75</width>
        <height>87</height>
    </image>
    <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>325</height>
    </image>
    <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
        <width>2500</width>
        <height>3750</height>
    </image>
    <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
        <width>75</width>
        <height>87</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
        <width>2500</width>
        <height>3750</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
        <width>100</width>
        <height>117</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
    <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image"><!-- slider in catalog image details -->
        <width>2500</width>
        <height>3750</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
        <width>100</width>
        <height>117</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image"><!-- slider in catalog image details -->
        <width>2500</width>
        <height>3750</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image"><!-- slider in catalog image details -->
        <!--<width>467</width>
        <height>544</height>-->
<width>2500</width>
        <height>3750</height>
    </image>
```

Comment: magento  version ?? 2.1.6

Comment: no, 2.1.4........

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9395

Comment: thats not my case, my images all has same size, but magento make the image small when I upload it then he displays it in the big size on the frontend. so it looks small with a big white frame

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is not good solution to change in core files.so use https://bitbucket.org/fred_imgmedia/imageproccess.git extension for the same  will  work for you.

`Magento\Framework\File\Uploader.php` contain constants MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT & MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH which is set to 1200 by default
[image]

or you can change in

`magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml`  same